# Templates when unit testing a Flask application

Tags: python, unit-testing, templates, flask

I'm writing unit tests for a Flask application that has roughly the following organization:

```
/myapplication
    runner.py
    /myapplication
        __init__.py
    /special
        __init__.py
        views.py
        models.py
    /static
    /templates
        index.html
        /special
            index_special.html
    /tests
        __init__.py
        /special
            __init__.py
            test_special.py
```

In particular, I want to test that the `special` module works as expected.

I have defined the following:

- in `special/views.py`:

  ```
  mod = Blueprint('special', __name__, template_folder="templates")
  @mod.route('/standard')
  def info():
      return render_template('special/index_special.html')
  ```
- in `myapplication/__init__.py`:

  ```
  app = Flask(__name__)

  def register_blueprints(app):
       from special.views import mod as special_blueprint
       app.register_blueprint(special_blueprint, url_prefix='/special')

  register_blueprints(app)
  ```
- in `myapplication/tests/test_special.py`

  ```
  class TestSpecial:
      @classmethod
      def create_app(cls):
          app = Flask(__name__)
          register_blueprints(app)
          return app

      @classmethod
      def setup_class(cls):
          cls.app = cls.create_app()
          cls.client = cls.app.test_client()

      def test_connect(self):
          r = self.client.get('/standard')
          assert r.status_code == 200
  ```

While the application itself works fine, the `test_connect` unit-test fails with a `TemplateNotFound: special/index_special.html` exception.

How could I tell the tests where to find the corresponding templates ? Bypassing the rendering of templates using [Flask-testing](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/) is not really an option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `template_folder` to the application object constructor:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates')
```

You may have to use an absolute path, I'm not sure.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask

I mostly tend to have a `create_app` function with my application code and use that in my tests, just so the application object is consistent. I'll only create a separate app if I want to test a single blueprint or something small in isolation.

```
def create_app(conf_obj=BaseSettings, conf_file='/etc/mysettings.cfg'):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(conf_obj)
    app.config.from_pyfile(conf_file, silent=True)
    .... blueprints etc
    return app
```

Then in my tests:

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app(TestSettings)
        ....
```

Comment: Using the `template_folder` argument is not advisable, it turns out: the templates may refer to some routes that won't be properly configured. Using the factory approach you describe is the way to go, provided blueprints are properly defined (and mixing blueprints with the standard `@app.route` way is asking for troubles...)